# Is It true that If the angular momentum is zero with respect to any point then the system is at rest?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, reference-frames, statics

If the angular momentum is zero with respect to any point, surely the system is at rest. It is intuitive that this is the case but I would like to *prove* it. I guess supposing the opposite leads to contradiction, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have two choices of origin point $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O}'$, where $\vec{R}$ is the vector pointing from $\mathcal{O}$ to $\mathcal{O}'$.  It is straightforward to show that the angular momenta $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{L}'$ of any system with respect to $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O}'$ (respectively) are related by
$$
\vec{L} = \vec{L}' + \vec{R} \times \vec{P}
$$
where $\vec{P}$ is the net momentum of the system.   (The proof is left as an exercise for the OP.)

If $\vec{L} = \vec{L}' = 0$, then it follows that $\vec{R}$ is some scalar multiple of $\vec{P}$.  And if we further assume that $\vec{L}'' = 0$ according to a third origin point whose origin is not colinear with $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O}'$, then it must be the case that $\vec{P} = 0$.

Note that this does not necessarily mean that the system is completely at rest;  all we can prove from this is that the center of mass of the system is at rest.  Also note that this can be extended to say that if the angular momentum is equal (but not necessarily zero) with respect to three non-colinear origin points, then $\vec{P} = 0$.

Comment: Great! Looking to the way how transform L when we change the point, simply solve the problem: we are sure that total momentum is zero, but clearly It is not sufficient to say that the system is at rest (my intuition in writing the question was wrong).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this before I saw the other answers by Michael Seifert and John Alexiou had been posted so there is some overlap, but I'll post it anyway.

The answer depends on what you mean by rest. Zero angular momentum about every point implies that the center of mass of is at rest, but the constituents of the system can still be in motion. If the system is a rigid body, then yes, zero angular momentum implies complete rest in the sense of zero velocity at each point on the body.

The angular momentum of a general system about point $\vec R$ is
$$\vec L=\sum_i (\vec r_i-\vec R)\times \vec p_i$$
where $\vec r_i$ is the position of a small mass $i$ in the system, with momentum $\vec p_i.$ Rearranging,
$$\vec R\times\sum_i \vec p_i=\vec L-\sum_i(\vec r_i\times \vec p_i) $$
or
$$\vec R\times \vec P=\vec L-\vec L_0.$$
where $\vec P$ is the total linear momentum of the system and $\vec L_0$ is the angular momentum about the origin. If the angular momentum is zero about any point, the right hand side is zero, so $\vec R\times\vec P=0$. Since this must hold for every $\vec R$, it follows that $\vec P=0$, i.e. the total linear momentum is zero. By definition,
$$\vec P=M \vec v_{\text{CM}} $$
where $M$ is the total mass of the system and $\vec v_{\text{CM}}$ is the velocity of the center of mass, so the center of mass must be at rest.

Constituents of the system can still be in motion. The simplest example is two particles of equal mass moving away from each other with equal speed. Note that the center of mass is still fixed.

If the system is a rigid body, note first that the motion of a rigid body at any instant can be decomposed into a rotation (characterized by an angular velocity $\vec \omega$) about any point, plus a translation (characterized by a linear velocity $\vec v$). Choosing this point to be the center of mass, since $\vec P = 0$ implies $\vec v_{\text{CM}}=0$, there is no translation, i.e. the motion of the rigid body is a pure rotation about the center of mass. However, any rotation would yield a non-zero angular momentum: specifically, the momentum about the center of mass is $\vec L=\text{I}\vec\omega$ where $\vec L$ and the inertia tensor $\text{I}$ are with respect to the center of mass. Therefore the rigid body will be at rest, in the sense of no translational or rotational motion.

Comment: "P=0 for a rigid body implies that the body is either at rest, or rotating about the center of mass with no translation". This is intuitive but intuition often fails, how can be proved?

Comment: @Haumea I've expanded my answer to address your question.

Comment: Thank you. After all Ptot = 0 implies Vcm = 0 and the fundamental formula of rigid motions leads to Vp = omega x (Rp-Rcm), which can be taken as a definition of rotary motion (rest if omega is zero).  I can find this satisfactory.

Comment: Your discussion of a non-rigid body is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Angular momentum tells you where in space the axis of the momentum vector is.

Consider a particle moving in a straight line.

The magnitude of angular momentum $| \vec{L} |$ and the magnitude of momentum $|\vec{p}|$ are related with

$$ | \vec{L} | = h\, | \vec{p} | $$

where $h$ the minimum perpendicular distance to the line the particle is moving in. This is called the *moment arm* of momentum, and angular momentum is viewed as the moment of momentum, just as torque is the moment of a force.

So if $| \vec{L} | = 0$, then either of two senarios are true

- The moment arm is zero $h=0$ and the path of the particle goes through the origin.
- Momentum is zero $|\vec{p}|=0$

If by definition $h  \neq 0$ by the problem statement, then only the second option is valid.

The last part is to prove $| \vec{L} | = h\, | \vec{p} |$, and its geometric meaning. This is done by considering the line of motion as a ray, with starting vector $\vec{r}_0$ and direction $\vec{v}$ such that the position of the particle is $$ \vec{r} = \vec{r}_0 + \vec{v} t$$

Angular momentum is $\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p}$ or

$$ \require{cancel} \vec{L} = \vec{r}_0 \times \vec{p} + t ( \cancel{ \vec{v} \times \vec{p} }) $$

Geometrically the parallelogram defined by the vectors $\vec{r}_0$ and $\vec{p}$ has area $| \vec{L} | = | \vec{r}_0 \times \vec{p} |$. But the area of the parallelogram is also the base |$\vec{p}$| times the height $h$ (which the perpendicular distance from the base).

$$ | \vec{L} | = h  \, |\vec{p}| $$

There are other ways to prove the above, but I find the geometric argument the simplest to conceptualize.

In general, you can recover the point closest to the origin $\vec{r}_H$ on the line with

$$ \vec{r}_H = \frac{ \vec{p} \times \vec{L} }{ |\vec{p} |^2} $$

which leads to $| \vec{r}_H | = h$. This is easy to prove since $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{L}$ are perpendicular and $| \vec{p} \times \vec{L} | = |\vec{p}| \, |\vec{P}|$

Using the vector triple product to expand on $\vec{p} \times \vec{L} = \vec{p} \times ( \vec{r}_H \times \vec{p})$ that above expression is proven.

$$ \vec{p} \times \vec{L} = \vec{r}_H ( \vec{p} \cdot \vec{p}) - \vec{p} (\cancel{ \vec{p} \cdot \vec{r}_H }) $$

$$ \vec{r}_H = \frac{ \vec{p} \times \vec{L} }{ \vec{p} \cdot \vec{p} } $$

In summary, angular momentum $\vec{L}$ only tells you where in space the line of action of momentum is by providing the point closest to the origin. The direction of the line of action and magnitude is defined by $\vec{p}$ alone.

So a constraint of $\vec{L}=0$ leads to the conclusion that either the line goes through the origin $|\vec{r}_H| = h = 0$ or that the particle has no momentum $\vec{p}=0$.

Answer (score -1):

*My earlier response was not correct, sorry.  Here is my updated response.*

A system does not have to be at rest to have zero angular momentum with respect to any point.  Here is a simple example; see the figure below.  Two equal masses move in opposite directions with equal speed.  The total angular momentum about any point $O$ is zero but the system is not at rest.
See the more detailed response by @Puk; a rigid body is not the most general case.

[image]

Comment: This system has angular momentum about any point that it not collinear with the direction of the momentum and the center of mass. Perhaps that is what is meant by pole.

Comment: in Italian it says "polo" I'm not sure about the English word, at the moment it doesn't come to mind.  it is simply the point with respect to which we calculate the moment.  the vector r starts from the "pole" and ends in a moving material particle.

Comment: Angular Momentum of A Particle, Moving in A Straight Line, About a Point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sDOO1C_1wE&ab_channel=KhanAcademyPhysics

Comment: An actual, simple application of a ball moving in a strauight line having rotational momentum: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viLpmZtQYzE&ab_channel=KhanAcademyPhysics

Comment: Yes, my mistake.  I updated my response.